# Is it possible for screen readers to differentiate <a> link text?

Tags: html, hyperlink, accessibility, screen-readers

I basically have the following series of links like the HTML below:

```
<a href="http://mylink0.com">Learn more</a>
<a href="http://mylink1.com">Learn more</a>
<a href="http://mylink2.com">Learn more</a>
<a href="http://mylink3.com">Learn more</a>
```

All the link text are the same. I read this is horrible for a screen reader user. I'd like to differentiate what the screen reader would read even though I have the same link for all the links. Is this possible?

```
<a href="http://mylink0.com">Learn more</a> Screen reader should read Red Store
<a href="http://mylink1.com">Learn more</a> Screen reader should read Blue Store
<a href="http://mylink2.com">Learn more</a> Screen reader should read Green Store
<a href="http://mylink3.com">Learn more</a> Screen reader should read Yellow Store
```

Comment: Multiple "Learn more" are horrible even if you don't use a screen reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The W3C has [a document about this sort of thing](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_aria-label_for_link_purpose). You add `aria-label` attributes to your links to give replacement content text meant for assistive technologies.

```
<a href="http://mylink0.com" aria-label="Red Store">Learn more</a>
```

Though you may wish to reconsider how the links are labeled to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

I know you have accepted an answer already, but it is better for all users to make descriptive links and not rely on ARIA. ARIA is a bridging technology, not a workaround for screen readers.

I have quoted the below article below the link. <s>I will reformat it later when not on mobile.</s>

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/learn-more-links/

> So, if you use descriptive labels instead of standalone Learn More text, your copy will benefit in several ways:
>
> - Links will be more accessible.
> - Links will be more enticing to users and potentially more persuasive.
> - Users will feel more confident as they click from page to page.
> - More keywords on the page will help search-engine optimization.
> - Meaningful links will stand alone and help users who are scanning the page.
>
> […]
>
> Option 1: Use keywords that describe the link’s destination.
>
> […]
>
> Option 2. Retain the Learn More format and add descriptive keywords.
>
> […]
>
> Option 3: Convert the preceding-paragraph heading into the only link.

Comment: After reading upon it some more, the content definitely has to change.

Answer (score 1):

Links like `Learn more`, `Details`, etc. are bad practice.

Consider getting rid of such links, and use meaningful text (typically the block title) as a link instead.

If you are absolutely not able to change current design, consider placing the meaningful text into the `title` attribute of the `Learn more` link.